# how to sort array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I want sort array which is shown below by bayid

Array is the array Name

```
[
 Object { bayid="35",  status=0},
 Object { bayid="1",  status=0},
 Object { bayid="37",  status=0}
]
```

`Array.sort(function(a,b){return b.bayid >a.bayid})`

I am not sure what is this function returning but i want to write a function which returns the sorted array as shown below

```
[
 Object { bayid="37",  status=0},
 Object { bayid="35",  status=0},
 Object { bayid="1",  status=0}
]
```

how to do it please help

Comment: That's exactly what you're doing, sorting the array, but it's sorted in place

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: So, do you want what you already have, just in reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code and with some of the solutions is that they incorrectly [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort) by string value: `b.bayid > a.bayid`

This appears to work correctly until we set the last element to bayid="100" and find that it returns `"35" > "100" = true`. The array is sorted incorrectly.

To fix this bug, we could use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)(a.bayid) or simply prefix it with a plus like (+a.bayid) to sort by numeric rather than string values. And now all is happy in array land.

**Run the snippet below to see the results of both methods of sorting.**

```js
var _a = [
  
    {bayid: "35",  status: 0 },
    {bayid: "1",   status: 0 },
    {bayid: "100", status: 0 }

].sort(function(a, b) { 
  return b.bayid > a.bayid;   // <== to compare string values
});

print('Test 1: Sort by string', _a );


_a = [
  
    {bayid: "35",  status: 0 },
    {bayid: "1",   status: 0 },
    {bayid: "100", status: 0 }

].sort(function(a, b) { 
  return +b.bayid > +a.bayid;   // <== to compare numeric values
});

print('Test 2: Sort by number', _a );


function print( s, o ) {
  window.stdout.innerHTML += s + '\n' + JSON.stringify(o, false, '  ') + '\n\n';
}
```

```html
Scroll down to view result:<br>
<xmp id="stdout"></xmp>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var objArray = [{ bayid:"35",  status:0},{ bayid:"1",  status:0}, { bayid:"37",  status:0}];

    function compare(a,b) {
    
      if (a.bayid < b.bayid )
        return 1;
      else if (a.bayid > b.bayid)
        return -1;
      else 
        return 0;
    }
    
    console.log(objArray.sort(compare));
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works as it should.
read up more on .sort function [here](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort)

```js
    var arr = [{ bayid:"35",  status:0}, { bayid:"1",  status:0}, { bayid:"37",  status:0}];

    var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {return b.bayid > a.bayid});

    console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of those JSON items seems to be a bit confused in your code.
Try this instead

```
var _a = [
{ bayid : 35,  status : 0},
{ bayid : 1,  status : 0},
{ bayid : 37,  status : 0}
] ;

_a.sort(function(a,b){return b.bayid >a.bayid}) ;
```